# Combine results from SQL query and take all combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question in SQL Server. I have the following table:

```
ROUTES = the route ID
STATIONS = the station ID
ORDER = the order the train pass from the stations
STOPS? = if the train stops at this station then is equal to 1 otherwise 0
```

Sample data:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
ROUTES      STATIONS    ORDER       STOPS?
-----------------------------------------------------
R1          S1          1           1
R1          S2          2           1
R1          S3          3           1
R1          S4          4           1
R1          S5          5           1
R2          S2          1           1
R2          S3          2           1
R2          S4          3           1
R3          S1          1           1
R3          S2          2           1
R3          S7          3           1
R3          S4          4           1
R3          S5          5           1
R3          S6          6           1
R4          S1          1           1
R4          S2          2           1
R4          S3          3           0
R4          S4          4           1
R5          S2          1           1
R5          S3          2           0
R5          S4          3           1
R6          S3          1           1
R6          S4          2           0
R6          S5          3           0
R6          S6          4           1
R7          S2          1           1
R7          S3          2           0
R7          S4          3           0
R7          S5          4           1
```

So concluding we have the following routes:

```
R1: S1-S2-S3-S4-S5
R2: S2-S3-S4
R3: S1-S2-S7-S4-S5-S6
R4: S1-S2-S3-S4
R5: S2-S3-S4
R6: S3-S4-S5-S6
R7: S2-S3-S4-S5
```

**Let's assume the S2 and S4 are connecting stations**

This mean that if a train from a route stops there (STOPS=1) a passenger can get off the train and take another train from another route

So we have a table mentioning the connecting station

```
conn_stations
--------------
S2
S4
```

My question is how can I get all possible combinations of routes that depart for example from station S1 and arrive at station S5. A passenger can change routes according to the data above we should take the following results (routes):

```
R1:     S1-S2-S3-S4-S5
R3:     S1-S2-S7-S4-S5
temp1:  S1-S2(from R1)-S7-S4-S5(from R3)
temp2:  S1-S2(from R3)-S3-S4(from R1)-S5(from R3)
temp3:  S1-S2-S3-S4(from R1)-S5(from R3)
e.t.c
```

I hope you understand what am asking.

If it helps I have a table that says the distanced between two stations, this indicated also which stations are connected

```
Station A   Station B   Distance
-------------------------------------
S1          S2          5
S2          S3          1
S2          S7          8
S3          S4          15
S4          S5          16
S5          S6          25
S7          S4          10
```

Comment: how are transfer (connecting) stations identified?  Is there a station table with a marker?  Also, do you need the routes displayed?  temp1 and R3 have the same sequence, should they be in the results twice as you've posted?

Comment: yes there is a table, i added it above just now!

Comment: This is not a set-based calculation and you will need procedural code to accomplish this.  Do you absolutely need to do this using T-SQL, or can you use something else (such as a C# UDF, perhaps)?

Comment: This is a grap/map problem that SQL isn't really suited for. Perhaps there is a scripting/programming language you are familiar with where you could implement this solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what you final table adds to the situation, nor how it indicates which stations are connected.

Comment: If routes are bi-directional, obviously there are an infinite number of solutions also (they could spend a lot of time on R5 and (reversed) R5 traveling between S2 and S4 many times). Is this something that needs to be dealt with?

Comment: no, lets assume that routes are one way. so you don't need to worry about bi-directional routes

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier if you don't have to include all the interim stations between a connecting station and the end station, but here's what I did for the direct routes:

```
select sroute, sstation, sorder, eroute, estation, eorder
from
 (select route as sroute, station as sstation, order as sorder
  from path
  where station = "s1" and stops = 1) pstart inner join
 (select route as eroute, station as estation, order as eorder
  from path
  where station = "s5" and stops = 1) pend on
 pstart.sroute = pend.eroute) direct
```

and routes through one connecting station:

```
SELECT sroute, sstation, sorder, 
        croute, cstation, corder,
        oroute, ostation, oorder,
        p.route , p.station, p.ORDER
FROM
    (SELECT sroute, sstation, sorder, 
                     croute, cstation, corder, 
                     p.route AS oroute, p.station AS ostation, p.ORDER AS oorder
    FROM
         (SELECT sroute, sstation, sorder, 
                 p.route AS croute, p.station AS cstation, p.ORDER AS corder
          FROM
              (SELECT route AS sroute, station AS sstation, ORDER AS sorder
               FROM path
               WHERE station = "s1" AND stops = 1
               ) pstart INNER JOIN
               path p ON 
               pstart.route = p.route INNER JOIN 
               conn_stations c ON 
               p.station = c.station
          WHERE p.stops = 1
          ) conn INNER JOIN 
          path p ON 
          conn.cstation = p.station
          WHERE p.stops = 1 AND p.route <> conn.route 
      ) conn_off INNER JOIN
        path p ON 
        conn_off.oroute = p.route
WHERE p.stops = 1 AND p.station = "s5"
```

but the number of connecting stations would be reflected in the SQL, and you'd be better off using a programming tool.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I reckon there are 39 routes from `S1` to `S5`, in your sample data (if I've got my query right). I don't necessarily believe that SQL is the right tool for this job (especially if, as per comments, routes become bidirectional).

The query:

```
declare @StartStation char(2)
declare @EndStation char(2)
select @StartStation = 'S1'
select @EndStation = 'S5'

;With PartialRoutes as (
    select Route,Station,CONVERT(varchar(max),Station) as CurrentPath,RouteOrder,1 as HasTransferred,CONVERT(varchar(max),Route) as RoutesTaken,Stop
    from
        @Routes r
    where
        r.Station = @StartStation and r.Stop = 1
    union all
    --Continue on current route
    select pr.Route,r.Station,pr.CurrentPath + '-' + r.Station,r.RouteOrder,0,RoutesTaken,r.Stop
    from
        PartialRoutes pr
            inner join
        @Routes r
            on
                pr.Route = r.Route and
                pr.RouteOrder = r.RouteOrder - 1
    union all
    --Transfers
    select r.Route,r.Station,pr.CurrentPath,r.RouteOrder,1,RoutesTaken + '-' + r.Station + '(' + pr.Route + ',' + r.Route + ')',r.Stop
    from
        PartialRoutes pr
            inner join
        @Connections c
            on
                pr.Station = c.Station
            inner join
        @Routes r
            on
                pr.Route != r.Route and
                pr.Station = r.Station
    where
        pr.HasTransferred = 0 --Prevents us transferring multiple times in a single station
            and r.Stop = 1
)
select * from PartialRoutes where Station = @EndStation and Stop=1 option (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Results:

```
Route Station CurrentPath         RouteOrder  HasTransferred RoutesTaken
----- ------- ------------------- ----------- -------------- --------------------------
R7    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      4           0              R4-S2(R4,R7)
R3    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R4-S2(R4,R7)-S4(R7,R3)
R1    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R4-S2(R4,R7)-S4(R7,R1)
R3    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R4-S2(R4,R5)-S4(R5,R3)
R1    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R4-S2(R4,R5)-S4(R5,R1)
R3    S5      S1-S2-S7-S4-S5      5           0              R4-S2(R4,R3)
R1    S5      S1-S2-S7-S4-S5      5           0              R4-S2(R4,R3)-S4(R3,R1)
R3    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R4-S2(R4,R2)-S4(R2,R3)
R1    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R4-S2(R4,R2)-S4(R2,R1)
R1    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R4-S2(R4,R1)
R3    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R4-S2(R4,R1)-S4(R1,R3)
R3    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R4-S4(R4,R3)
R1    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R4-S4(R4,R1)
R7    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      4           0              R3-S2(R3,R7)
R3    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R3-S2(R3,R7)-S4(R7,R3)
R1    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R3-S2(R3,R7)-S4(R7,R1)
R3    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R3-S2(R3,R5)-S4(R5,R3)
R1    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R3-S2(R3,R5)-S4(R5,R1)
R3    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R3-S2(R3,R4)-S4(R4,R3)
R1    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R3-S2(R3,R4)-S4(R4,R1)
R3    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R3-S2(R3,R2)-S4(R2,R3)
R1    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R3-S2(R3,R2)-S4(R2,R1)
R1    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R3-S2(R3,R1)
R3    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R3-S2(R3,R1)-S4(R1,R3)
R3    S5      S1-S2-S7-S4-S5      5           0              R3
R1    S5      S1-S2-S7-S4-S5      5           0              R3-S4(R3,R1)
R7    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      4           0              R1-S2(R1,R7)
R3    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R1-S2(R1,R7)-S4(R7,R3)
R1    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R1-S2(R1,R7)-S4(R7,R1)
R3    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R1-S2(R1,R5)-S4(R5,R3)
R1    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R1-S2(R1,R5)-S4(R5,R1)
R3    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R1-S2(R1,R4)-S4(R4,R3)
R1    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R1-S2(R1,R4)-S4(R4,R1)
R3    S5      S1-S2-S7-S4-S5      5           0              R1-S2(R1,R3)
R1    S5      S1-S2-S7-S4-S5      5           0              R1-S2(R1,R3)-S4(R3,R1)
R3    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R1-S2(R1,R2)-S4(R2,R3)
R1    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R1-S2(R1,R2)-S4(R2,R1)
R1    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R1
R3    S5      S1-S2-S3-S4-S5      5           0              R1-S4(R1,R3)
```

I've added a column on the end that shows the routes that were followed, where e.g. `R4-S2(R4,R7)-S4(R7,R6)` means that they started on route `R4`, then at `S2` they transferred to route `R7`, then at `S4` they transferred to route `R6`.

Hopefully, you can take this query and modify it as you need to (i.e. I still don't know the relevance of the final table in your question).

**EDIT** I added a final condition on the query that the train needs to `Stop` at the destination station. I'm not sure if this is a requirement, but it doesn't affect the results for `S1` to `S5` anyway. It's easy enough to take back out.

---

Based on this data setup:

```
declare @Routes table (Route char(2) not null, Station char(2) not null,RouteOrder int not null,Stop bit not null)
insert into @Routes (Route,Station,RouteOrder,Stop) values
('R1','S1',1,1),('R1','S2',2,1),('R1','S3',3,1),('R1','S4',4,1),('R1','S5',5,1),
('R2','S2',1,1),('R2','S3',2,1),('R2','S4',3,1),
('R3','S1',1,1),('R3','S2',2,1),('R3','S7',3,1),('R3','S4',4,1),('R3','S5',5,1),('R3','S6',6,1),
('R4','S1',1,1),('R4','S2',2,1),('R4','S3',3,0),('R4','S4',4,1),
('R5','S2',1,1),('R5','S3',2,0),('R5','S4',3,1),
('R6','S3',1,1),('R6','S4',2,0),('R6','S5',3,0),('R6','S6',4,1),
('R7','S2',1,1),('R7','S3',2,0),('R7','S4',3,0),('R7','S5',4,1)

declare @Connections table (Station char(2) not null)
insert into @Connections (Station) values ('S2'),('S4')
```